# What do children own?

Tags: halacha, children-parenting, choshen-mishpat-civil-law

Is there truth to the saying I heard in orthodox houses, namely that if the parents support the children (even after 13/12) everything belongs to them?

What is the source of this (truth or falsehood)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Shulchan Aruch 270:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%98_%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%91)

> מציאת בנו ובתו הסמוכים על שולחנו אע"פ שהם גדולים ומציאת בתו הנערה אע"פ שאינה סומכת על שולחנו ומציאת עבדו ושפחתו הכנענים ומציאת אשתו הרי אלו שלו
>
> (וה"ה אם הרויחו בסחורה או במלאכה (נ"י ססי' קע"ז בשם עיטור) אבל אם מת אינו מוריש מלאכת בן אחד לשאר יורשיו) (הגהות שניות דמרדכי דב"מ)‏

Comment: [shulchan aruch choshen mishpat 270.2](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Choshen_Mishpat.270?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all)

Comment: my translation, what his son and daughter that are eating by his table (he is supporting them) even thought they are big (older then 13/12.5 (and have 2 pubic hair)) what they find (that does not belong to anyone) belongs to him, and (same by) his daughter that is a naara (between 12 and 12.5) even is she is not by his table (she supports herself), (same by) his non jewish slave/maidservant, and what his wife finds these belong to him

Comment: (the ramo) in parentheses, the same law applies to what they gain in business or for working, but if he dies he does not leave as his inheritance (the money made from the) work of the one to the rest of his inheritors

Comment: very much [tzuras hadaf](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=cm_x11196)