# Can someone stop being supported by his father without his father's permission?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

From the shulchan aruch ([yora deya 240.5 end](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.240.5?with=all))

> אֲבָל חַיָּב לְכַבְּדוֹ בְּגוּפוֹ, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁמִּתּוֹךְ כָּךְ בָּטֵל מִמְּלַאכְתּוֹ, וְיִצְטָרֵךְ לְחַזֵּר עַל הַפְּתָחִים. וְדַוְקָא דְּאִית לַבֵּן מְזוֹנוֹת לְאִיתְזוּנֵי הַהוּא יוֹמָא, אֲבָל אִי לֵית לֵיהּ, לֹא מְחֻיָּב לְבַטֵּל מִמְּלַאכְתּוֹ וְלַחֲזֹר עַל הַפְּתָחִים.‏

I understand that the mitzvah of respecting my father is even not to work to respect him as long as I have what to eat for today.

My question:

1. If I do not have what to eat (that belongs to me) for today (so no mitzvah not to work (see source above)) and my father offers to feed me (or commands me to eat his food), does that make the mitzvah of respecting my father and not working applicable to me?

   2. If not, (then in my understanding it is preferable that I make money and not live off tzedoka/[gifts](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=kLLsj8qZVUY) of my father (the one that hates gifts will live))
      how can I make money if I am (Ashkenazi and) still living in my father's house and everything that I make belongs to him [shulchan aruch choshen mishpat 270.2](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Choshen_Mishpat.270.2?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all).

for translation See comment on answer  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/64925/5120

Sources appreciated. (This is a theoretical question not practical.)

Comment: @DannySchoemann I am NOT paying rent, by getting an answer to this question I will see if it is possible for me to pay the rent, how can I make the question more clear?

Comment: I don't know, as I still don't understand what is happening. Your father is housing you and clothing you but you don't want him to feed you? Or are you saying you want to move out (and maybe back into the house as a paying boarder)? Then you're not סומך על שולחן אביו and the money you earn is yours. What are you trying to ask?

Comment: @DannySchoemann if I am busy honoring my father maybe I do not have a right to move out

Comment: @DannySchoemann maybe I have the right but it is a mitzvah not to

Comment: @DannySchoemann if I understand my source correctly, and if the answer to number 1 is that I am still obligated to honor him even if the food for the one day is coming from him

Comment: @DannySchoemann see the source in my answer

Comment: @DannySchoemann first I found the answer, this was my question the whole time, I do not see a significant difference, just a different way of saying the same thing (maybe more clearly)

Comment: @DannySchoemann you said before it is unclear  what I am asking, so I think I only improved my question, I still want an answer (I already made a bounty but it did not help)

Answer (score 1):

This halacha is not a reason not to work, rather it is a petur that one does not need to actively take care of his father if it means he will not have what to eat for that day.
If one does not have enough for that day he can go work until he has enough for that day.
if he does not have a set job that he can rely on for tomorrow he is patur until he has enough for 3 days.(see rishon litzion).

In regard to you making money/working because you live in your fathers house does not mean what you work for belongs to your father, only what you get in a unexpected matter (like you find something...).

Comment: How can i find the rishon litzion? How do you understand וה"ה אם הרויחו בסחורה או במלאכה,?( I understand that this is only for ashkenazim)

Comment: Is it this http://hebrewbooks.org/36928

Comment: If yes what page

Comment: only what you get in a unexpected matter (like you find something...).   That is not what the ramo sais

Answer (score 0):

From the [Pele yoets in the end of kibud av vaim](http://www.peleyoetz.com/PeleYoetz.aspx?ID=181).
 it seems that you should not leave your fathers table with out his permission (this might be a **stringency** and not a legal obligation)